# Why does my login application in codeigniter give me this error?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api, google-signin, google-api-client

When I install google api client via composer in my ci project it throws the following error.

Fatal error: Declaration of CodeIgniter\Log\Logger::emergency($message, array $context = []): bool must be compatible with Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::emergency(Stringable|string $message, array $context = []): void in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginapp\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Log\Logger.php on line 158

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "CodeIgniter\Log\Logger" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginapp\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Config\Services.php:400 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\loginapp\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Config\BaseService.php(258): CodeIgniter\Config\Services::logger(false) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\loginapp\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Config\BaseService.php(199): CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService::__callStatic('logger', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\loginapp\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Config\Services.php(397): CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService::getSharedInstance('logger') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\loginapp\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Config\BaseService.php(258): CodeIgniter\Config\Services::logger(true) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\loginapp\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Common.php(810): CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService::__callStatic('logger', Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\loginapp\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Debug\Exceptions.php(131): log_message('critical', '{message}\nin {e...', Array) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\loginapp\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Debug\Exceptions.php(236): CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions->exceptionHandler(Object(ErrorException)) #7 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions->shutdownHandler() #8 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginapp\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Config\Services.php on line 400

How do I fix this?

I've tried different php versions and different google api client versions. I was expecting a normal login page but now I have this error.